# Custom Dropdown within Angular UI-Grid

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-grid

I'm playing around with the [new Angular UI-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/), and am having problems injecting a custom dropdown into a grid cell. [The built-in dropdown functionality](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/315_editable_cascading_dropdown) doesn't work for my project since you can only go so far to style a SELECT tag. I'd like to use [this swanky multi-select dropdown](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/), but it looks like the ui-grid's magic is either stopping my open dropdown event from propagating or my dropdown isn't able to be initialized on the fly.

Here's my example code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit class="grid"></div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>`
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  var grid;

    $scope.msData = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "John"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}];
    $scope.msSettings = {enableSearch: true, smartButtonMaxItems: 3, smartButtonTextConverter: function(itemText, originalItem) {return originalItem.id;}};

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name'}
      ,{ name: 'friends', displayName: 'Friends', editableCellTemplate: 'temp.html', width: '250', editDropdownValueLabel: 'friends'}
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      grid = gridApi.grid;
    }
  };

  $http.get('https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });

}]);
```

temp.html (edit cell template):

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="msData" selected-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" extra-settings="msSettings" checkboxes="true"></div>
```

When you double click the Friends cell, the select dropdown button appears, but clicking it doesn't expand the dropdown.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P4ONEaB7sDijFdUXXXNF?p=preview)

I've played around with a couple of other ways of doing a dropdown, but all have the same issue where the base element (button, link, etc) appears but the dropdown doesn't expand.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to stop the ui-grid from intercepting my click event (if that actually is what is causing the problem)? Or have any of you fine people implemented a similar custom dropdown in ui-grid before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you need to create a directive, not just a template.  Refer the discussion here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable about custom editors.

To get an idea of what that might look like, take a look at the edit.js file, and the bottom directive: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/features/edit/js/gridEdit.js

That last directive, for the file chooser, I added recently.  You'd need something like that (or perhaps more like the directive for uiGridEditDropdown, which I added a while back a little further up the file).

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, the common problem with using html-based widgets in UI-Grid is that individual cells as well as the grid itself are set up to prevent their contents from **overflowing**. This lets everything stay sized nice and normal but gets in the way when you want to show extra content like a custom dropdown.

You can get around this with [UI-Select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) because it has an `append-to-body` attribute that will absolutely position the element in the right place, but it will be appended to the document body, which gets rid of the overflow issue.

I have a write-up on the exact method for doing this here: http://brianhann.com/ui-grid-and-dropdowns/ . There may be ways to do the same thing with other widgets but it would probably require some extra coding or perhaps even forking them.